# How to update a varchar field only when it ends with (.%) in mysql with python

Tags: python, mysql

I want to loop and update all the fields that has entry like (abc.py) to (abc) or (def.exe) to (def)  where id = 2.

```
UPDATE column from table test
when column=abc.exe THEN column = abc
where id = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by [MySQL SUBSTRING_INDEX Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html), and I guess this question is not related to `python`.

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column = SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, '.', 1)
WHERE id = 2;
```

Comment: Delete last line above(WHERE id = 2) could finish your work without any loop.